# Django Rest Framework: Error when handle file upload by iOS Swift Client

Tags: swift, django, django-rest-framework

I have an issue when handling file upload by iOS Swift Client. I describe it totally below

My model:

```
def avatar_photo_upload(instance, filename):
    if filename:
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = 'avatar.%s' % (ext)
    else:
        filename = 'avatar.jpg'
    return "avatar/%s/%s" %('profile', filename)

class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.FileField("Uploaded avatar of profile", storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=avatar_photo_upload, null=True, blank=True)
```

My serializer:

```
class PhotoUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    file = ImageField(max_length=100000, allow_empty_file=False, use_url=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'file',
        ]
```

My view:

```
class UploadPhotoAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PhotoUpdateSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def upload_avatar(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
        logger.info('Information incoming!')
        if serializer.is_valid():
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            profile.avatar = request.FILES.get('file')
            profile.save()
            return Response({ 'status': 'ok', 'avatar': get_avatar_url(request, '300x300', 'user', profile.user_id) }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            logger.error('Toan Error' + str(serializer.errors))
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
```

Finally, this is my url:

```
url(r'^account/upload_avatar/$', UploadPhotoAPIView.as_view({'post': 'upload_avatar'}))
```

I believed that I make it all the right way until test API in iOS Swift, it return error:

Request by client:

```
func uploadImage(image:UIImage) {
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100)
    SRWebClient.POST("https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/")
        .data(imageData, fieldName:"file", data: ["filename":"avatar","ext":".jpg"])
        .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
            // process success response
        },failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
            // process failure response
        })
    }
```

Error traceback:

> [Request]: POST
>   https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/
>   [Response]:  { URL:
>   https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/ } {
>   Status Code: 501, Headers {
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           84
>       );
>       "Content-Type" =     (
>           "application/json"
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:41:31 GMT"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           cloudflare
>       );
>       Vary =     (
>           Origin
>       );
>       allow =     (
>           "POST, OPTIONS"
>       );
>       "cf-ray" =     (
>           "46787998dfaa8502-HKG"
>       );
>       "expect-ct" =     (
>           "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""
>       );
>       "x-frame-options" =     (
>           SAMEORIGIN
>       ); } } [Data]: 84 bytes [Result]: SUCCESS: {
>       file =     (
>           "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
>       ); } [Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 560860890.985, "Initial Response Time": 560860891.099, "Request Completed Time":
>   560860891.100, "Serialization Completed Time": 560860891.100, "Latency": 0.114 secs, "Request Duration": 0.115 secs, "Serialization
>   Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.115 secs }   ▿ request :
>   Optional
>       ▿ some : https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/
>         ▿ url : Optional
>           ▿ some : https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/
>             - _url : https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/
>         - cachePolicy : 0
>         - timeoutInterval : 60.0
>         - mainDocumentURL : nil
>         - networkServiceType : __C.NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType
>         - allowsCellularAccess : true
>         ▿ httpMethod : Optional
>           - some : "POST"
>         ▿ allHTTPHeaderFields : Optional>
>           ▿ some : 2 elements
>             ▿ 0 : 2 elements
>               - key : "Content-Type"
>               - value : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
>             ▿ 1 : 2 elements
>               - key : "Authorization"
>               - value : "JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyMSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJkdW9uZ251aGFiYW5nIiwiZXhwIjoyNDAzMTY4MDU5LCJlbWFpbCI6ImRyYWZ0bGlnb25ncXVhbjdAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.ZfDBOaAhKsRSpZl3mP87doR34UtlGISfeqJYlJnxcVI"
>         ▿ httpBody : Optional
>           ▿ some : 105 bytes
>             - count : 105
>             ▿ pointer : 0x00006000025d2510
>               - pointerValue : 105553155925264
>         - httpBodyStream : nil
>         - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
>         - httpShouldUsePipelining : false   ▿ response : Optional
>       - some :  { URL: https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/ } {
>   Status Code: 501, Headers {
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           84
>       );
>       "Content-Type" =     (
>           "application/json"
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:41:31 GMT"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           cloudflare
>       );
>       Vary =     (
>           Origin
>       );
>       allow =     (
>           "POST, OPTIONS"
>       );
>       "cf-ray" =     (
>           "46787998dfaa8502-HKG"
>       );
>       "expect-ct" =     (
>           "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""
>       );
>       "x-frame-options" =     (
>           SAMEORIGIN
>       ); } }   ▿ data : Optional
>       ▿ some : 84 bytes
>         - count : 84
>         ▿ pointer : 0x00006000025d0c00
>           - pointerValue : 105553155918848   ▿ result : SUCCESS: {
>       file =     (
>           "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
>       ); }
>       ▿ success : 1 element
>         ▿ 0 : 2 elements
>           - key : file
>           ▿ value : 1 element
>             - 0 : The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.   ▿ timeline : Timeline: { "Request Start Time":
>   560860890.985, "Initial Response Time": 560860891.099, "Request Completed Time": 560860891.100, "Serialization Completed Time":
>   560860891.100, "Latency": 0.114 secs, "Request Duration": 0.115 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.115 secs }
>       - requestStartTime : 560860890.984645
>       - initialResponseTime : 560860891.099072
>       - requestCompletedTime : 560860891.099792
>       - serializationCompletedTime : 560860891.099964
>       - latency : 0.11442697048187256
>       - requestDuration : 0.11514699459075928
>       - serializationDuration : 0.00017201900482177734
>       - totalDuration : 0.11531901359558105   ▿ _metrics : Optional
>       - some : (Task Interval) <_NSConcreteDateInterval: 0x600000b68980> (Start Date) 2018-10-10 10:41:30 +0000 + (Duration) 0.115085 seconds =
>   (End Date) 2018-10-10 10:41:31 +0000 (Redirect Count) 0 (Transaction
>   Metrics) (Request)  { URL:
>   https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/ }
>   (Response)  { URL:
>   https://api.com/api/v1/users/account/upload_avatar/ } {
>   Status Code: 501, Headers {
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           84
>       );
>       "Content-Type" =     (
>           "application/json"
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:41:31 GMT"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           cloudflare
>       );
>       Vary =     (
>           Origin
>       );
>       allow =     (
>           "POST, OPTIONS"
>       );
>       "cf-ray" =     (
>           "46787998dfaa8502-HKG"
>       );
>       "expect-ct" =     (
>           "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""
>       );
>       "x-frame-options" =     (
>           SAMEORIGIN
>       ); } } (Fetch Start) 2018-10-10 10:41:30 +0000 (Domain Lookup Start) (null) (Domain Lookup End) (null) (Connect Start) (null)
>   (Secure Connection Start) (null) (Secure Connection End) (null)
>   (Connect End) (null) (Request Start) 2018-10-10 10:41:30 +0000
>   (Request End) 2018-10-10 10:41:30 +0000 (Response Start) 2018-10-10
>   10:41:31 +0000 (Response End) 2018-10-10 10:41:31 +0000 (Protocol
>   Name) h2 (Proxy Connection) NO (Reused Connection) YES (Fetch Type)
>   Network Load

What is the issue and it come from server or client? Please give me a advice. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the content type as a multipart form data.

```
class UploadPhotoAPIView(ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = PhotoUpdateSerializer
   queryset = Profile.objects.all()
   parser_classes = (JSONParser, MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

  def upload_avatar(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user), data=request.data, context={"request": request})
    logger.info('Information incoming!')
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({ 'status': 'ok', 'avatar': get_avatar_url(request, '300x300', 'user', profile.user_id) }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        logger.error('Toan Error' + str(serializer.errors))
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
```

in client side send data in multipart form data

Comment: The issue in this case is Data Upload Requested from Client is not valid for serializer ``{ file = ( "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form." ); }``. Because iOS Swift cant request `file`, it just request NSData. So it cause this issue!